# How to visualize the Standard Bounded Metric

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a metric space with metric $d$. Define $d'(x,y)=\min\{d(x,y),1\}$ If we assume we are working on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $d(x,y)$ is the euclidean metric where we use open balls, how am I suppose to visualize $d'$? Basically, both metrics are equivalent for $d(x,y)$ less than or equal to $1$, but if $d(x,y)$ is greater than $1$, then $d'$ will just be one no matter how big the open balls are.

How do we draw an open ball on $\mathbb{R}^2$? Also I believe these two metrics induces the same topology, but again, I am having trouble visualizing why that would be the case.

Comment: The metrics are equivalent in the technical sense, rather than being equal for some values of x and y (as mentioned in below answer)

Answer (score 2):

Consider a conical kitchen sink of depth $1$ unit, embedded in a flat (infinite) draining board.

Pretend that $x$ is the point of the plug hole at the bottom of the sink (the analogy falls down here because a plug hole is not a point, but you get the idea).

The depth of the water is your $\epsilon$. The open $\epsilon$-ball is the surface of the water.

When $\epsilon$ is less than $1$, the open $\epsilon$-ball is in the sink, and is round like you expect.

When $\epsilon$ is greater than $1$, the sink has overflowed, and the surface of the water has now gone everywhere.

A proof that $d'$ is equivalent to $d$ can be found here:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Standard_Bounded_Metric_is_Metric/Topological_Equivalence